# python unit test patch mock method not returning the return values

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I am trying to write a test case `test_is_user_present()` which calls another function `execute_redshift_sql()` from `redshift_util.py` script

I set the expected return value from the function execute_redshift_sql() to `1` . But I never get this value returned from result after the function is called ! I also printed some values for debugging purpose

You can take a look at test case below

```
from mock import patch, Mock, MagicMock
from cia_admin_operations.redshift_util import  execute_redshift_sql
    @patch('cia_admin_operations.redshift_util.execute_redshift_sql')
    def test_is_user_present(mock_execute_redshift_sql):
        ldap_user = "dummy_user"
        mock_out = Mock()

        user_check_sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM pg_user WHERE usename = '{}';".format(ldap_user)

        mock_execute_redshift_sql.return_value = 1
        print(mock_execute_redshift_sql())

        result = execute_redshift_sql(mock_out, user_check_sql)
        print(result)
        print(result())
>       assert result() == 1
E       AssertionError: assert <Mock name='m...749067684720'> == 1
E         -<Mock name='mock.query().getresult()()' id='139749067684720'>
E         +1

test/test_cia_admin_operations.py:51: AssertionError
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
1
<Mock name='mock.query().getresult()' id='139749067684776'>
<Mock name='mock.query().getresult()()' id='139749067684720'>
```

redshift_util.py

```
def execute_redshift_sql(connection, sqlQuery):
    """Executes redshift query"""

    logger.info("Executing following SQL query :\n %s" % sqlQuery)

    try:
        result = connection.query(sqlQuery)
        logger.info("Redshift query is successfully executed.")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Query not executed : %s" % e)
        return None
    # return only if the result has some data
    if result:
        logger.info("Query result :\n %s" % result)
        return result.getresult()
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: That looks like the function imported in the test wasn't mocked - how do you import it? Apart from that, I don't understand what the test shall do, but I guess this is just a dummy version of the real test.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen: This is dummy version of test only. The imported function (``cia_admin_operations.redshift_util.execute_redshift_sql``) is mocked thats why you see this printed ``name='mock.query().getresult()'`` . What I am expecting is the function should return the return value I set for testing purpose.

Comment: Well, no, the function is not mocked. What you see is the result of the mocked argument `mock_out` in the unmocked function. The used function seems not to be the same as the mocked one, thus I asked to show how it is imported.

Comment: @MrBean Bremen: do you mean this function : execute_redshift_sql ? how do i mock this function to give a specific return value ?

Comment: Yes, I mean this function, and I suspect that you mock not the one you imported. Thus I asked you to show _how_ you import it. Please add the respective import to the question.

Comment: i already imported into the main script where the test case is running. let me update the code

Comment: @MrBeanBremen: I updated the code on how I imported the function !

Comment: I wonder.. Is this really taken from the CIA admin ops source code?! Sounds interesting..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to patch the function as it is imported. One possibility to fix this is to use:

```
from mock import patch, Mock
import cia_admin_operations.redshift_util

@patch('cia_admin_operations.redshift_util.execute_redshift_sql')
def test_is_user_present(mock_execute_redshift_sql):
    ldap_user = "dummy_user"
    mock_out = Mock()

    user_check_sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM pg_user WHERE usename = '{}';".format(ldap_user)

    mock_execute_redshift_sql.return_value = 1

    result = cia_admin_operations.redshift_util.execute_redshift_sql(mock_out, user_check_sql)
    print(result)
```

In your case, you had mocked the function from the package, but used a locally imported module. You always have to check [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).

Above, I adapted the import, you can also adapt the patching:

```
from mock import patch, Mock
from cia_admin_operations.redshift_util import execute_redshift_sql

@patch('redshift_test.execute_redshift_sql')
def test_is_user_present(mock_execute_redshift_sql):
    ldap_user = "dummy_user"
    mock_out = Mock()

    user_check_sql = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM pg_user WHERE usename = '{}';".format(ldap_user)

    mock_execute_redshift_sql.return_value = 1

    result = execute_redshift_sql(mock_out, user_check_sql)
    print(result)
```

(you have to substitute `redshift_test` for the name of your test module in the `patch` decorator)

Comment: Excellent ! this line worked `` cia_admin_operations.redshift_util.execute_redshift_sql(mock_out, user_check_sql)`` Missed to call with package !

Comment: This really help me understand how patching works! I've been using patch all along and did not find it a problem. As stated `The basic principle is that you patch where an object is looked up, which is not necessarily the same place as where it is defined.`

Obviously, it is easy to fall into this problem when refactoring a big class into smaller classes.