# Batling with pytest mock system and starting to be exhausted

Tags: mocking, pytest

Let's be honest: I never been confronted to something so counter intuitive it even seems non deterministic.

One of the class method I am testing create a object of type `BuildParser` then call some methods on it. I need to mock this object.

For some reasons I just cannot.
I put together a small exemple illustrating the issue:

```
import mock

from jenkins_kpi_tools.jenkins_utilities.build_parser import BuildParser


class ClassToTest(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def execute(self):
        build_parser = BuildParser("project", "job", "master")
        return build_parser.get_builds_info_over_the_last_weeks(2) # NOT A MOCK BUT A jenkins_kpi_tools.jenkins_utilities.build_parser.BuildParser

def test_execute():
    with mock.patch('jenkins_kpi_tools.jenkins_utilities.build_parser') as patched_build_parser:
        with mock.patch('jenkins_kpi_tools.jenkins_utilities.build_parser.BuildParser') as patched_parser:
            patched_build_parser.return_value = patched_parser
            patched_parser().get_builds_info_over_the_last_weeks.return_value = None

            test_parser = BuildParser("project", "job", "master") # NOT A MOCK BUT A jenkins_kpi_tools.jenkins_utilities.build_parser.BuildParser
            class_to_test = ClassToTest()
            class_to_test.execute()
```

What should I do to get a mocked object ?

Comment: You should check [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6). In your example you have a local `BuildParser` variable which you use, but patch the class in the original package. Also, there is no need to patch the _package_. Check for example my [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60882117/python-unit-test-patch-mock-method-not-returning-the-return-values/60964436#60964436).

Comment: Also note that this is not specific to pytest - `mock` is part of  `unittest` (since Python 3). You seem to use a separate mock package - this was only needed in Python 2.

Comment: If I understand well I would patch the import that is actually in the class. What would it be then: `mock.patch('ClassToTest.BuildParser')` ?

Comment: The import is in the module, not in the class. You need `mock.patch('module_with_class_to_test.BuildParser')`. In your example that would be the test module itself, but in your real code that would be the module path to the class to test.

Comment: I think I have trouble with this:

"However, consider the alternative scenario where instead of from a import SomeClass module b does import a and some_function uses a.SomeClass."

This means that in Python, writing `from a import Someclass` or `import a` are fundamentally two different things ?

Comment: They are different things not with respect to the behavior of the imported class, but to the identity of the imported object. In the first case, a copy of the class is created in the module itself. Normally, you won't notice this, but if you patch the class, you have to account for this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to MrBean Bremen, this works:

```
#sandbox.py
import mock

from jenkins_kpi_tools.jenkins_utilities.build_parser import BuildParser


class ClassToTest(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def execute(self):
        build_parser = BuildParser("project", "job", "master")
        return build_parser.get_builds_info_over_the_last_weeks(2)

def test_execute():
    with mock.patch('sandbox.BuildParser') as patched_parser:
        test_parser = BuildParser("project", "job", "master") 
        class_to_test = ClassToTest()

        patched_parser().get_builds_info_over_the_last_weeks.return_value = None
        assert class_to_test.execute() is None

        patched_parser().get_builds_info_over_the_last_weeks.return_value = "Toto"
        assert class_to_test.execute() == "Toto"
```