# How do I mock an internally used python function with pytest_mock?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I'm trying to mock a function that is internal this my `calc_base` method that uploads to s3. I don't want that running in tests, but I do want my tests to make sure I'm uploading the correct content to S3.

I have tried many configurations with `pytest-mock` but I can't seem to prevent the `put_s3_json` function's original implementation from being called.

I've created a minimal case here:

### Code:

```
# calc.py

def calc():
    return { "test": True }
```

```
# calc_base/s3.py

def put_s3_json(dict):
   # S3 upload code here...
   raise Exception("ORIGINAL METHOD")
```

```
# calc_base/run_calc.py

from .s3 import put_s3_json
def run_calc(calc):
    result = calc()
    put_s3_json(result)
```

### Test:

```
# calc_test.py

from calc import calc
from calc_base.run_calc import run_calc

def my_put_s3_json(s3_location: dict, dict: dict):
    raise Exception("MOCKED IMPLEMENTATION")

def test_calc(mocker):
    mocker.patch('calc_base.s3.put_s3_json', my_put_s3_json)
    run_calc(calc) # raises "ORIGINAL METHOD"
    # expected it to raise "MOCKED IMPLEMENTATION" instead
```

How can I let me test declare a mock for the `put_s3_json` function?

Comment: You need to use `patch('calc_base.run_calc.put_s3_json', ...)`, see [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python unit test patch mock method not returning the return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60882117/python-unit-test-patch-mock-method-not-returning-the-return-values) (this has been answered many times, I just picked one of my own answers as I found it first...)